# How can I relate two tables in Leaflet

Tags: database, leaflet

I am mapping bibliographic information of Mars and would like to relate two tables(key column: feature_ID) in Leaflet. My objective is to show pop up of the csv table 2 info window when clicking a feature in the geojson table 1. However, I have no idea how to do this. Does anyone have any idea where should I refer to?

```
$.getJSON("mapdata.geojson",function(hoodData){
  L.geoJson( hoodData  , {
style: function(feature){
  var fillColor,
      number_of_papers = feature.properties.number_of_papers;
  if ( number_of_papers > 80 ) fillColor = "#006837";
  else if ( number_of_papers > 40 ) fillColor = "#31a354";
  else if ( number_of_papers > 20 ) fillColor = "#78c679";
  else if ( number_of_papers > 10 ) fillColor = "#c2e699";
  else if ( number_of_papers > 0 ) fillColor = "#ffffcc";
  else fillColor = "#f7f7f7";  // no data
  return { color: "#999", weight: 1, fillColor: fillColor, fillOpacity: .6 };
},
onEachFeature: function( feature, layer ){
  layer.bindPopup( "<strong>" + feature.properties.Clean_Feature_Name + "</strong><br/>" + "Number of Papers: " + feature.properties.number_of_papers + "<br/>" + "Number of Citing Papers: " + feature.properties.number_of_citing_papers + "<br/>" + "Number of self citations: " + feature.properties.number_of_self_citations + "<br/>" + "Total number of citations: " + feature.properties.total_number_of_citations + "<br/>" + "Number of referred citations: " + feature.properties.total_number_of_refereed_citations )
 }
}  ).addTo(map);
```

Map I created so far: https://shinjjo.github.io/heatmap.html
Data: https://github.com/shinjjo/shinjjo.github.io

The Table 1 has geographic information (geojson)
[image]

The Table 2 has publication information (csv)
Table 2
[image]

Comment: Looks like you are trying to do many things. Display GeoJSON on a Leaflet map, retrieve data from a CSV file, associate it to your GeoJSON, add interactivity, and possibly some sort of popup / panel to display associated data. If you need help for any of these steps, feel free to open a specific question with your code and exact troubles. It would be difficult to help you with all that at once, especially given the little details you provide.

Comment: @ghybs Thank you for your adivce. This link will tell you more detail.. I have not tried something to relate the two tables though. Leaflet map https://shinjjo.github.io/heatmap.html / mapdata(geojson) and publication information(csv) https://github.com/shinjjo/shinjjo.github.io

Comment: Thanks for the links to additional details, but it is highly preferred to provide such details within your question body. The rationale being (among other things) that your question should also help future visitors, and external resources may go down and kill your post interest.